# Horizontal Scroll when Navigation menu translates webpage with overflow-hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm currently working on my very first personal page! I'm getting horizontal scroll on smaller media queries where I shouldn't and I cant track down the culprit. All containers are set to 100% width and have their overflow-x hidden. Once the page reaches 1200px in width the side navigation collapses, however once you toggle the 'hamburger' the menu should slide out and push the contents of the main section out and hide the overflow until an anchor point is selected in the menu. At which point the page should shift back to where it was and scroll to the desired section. Something I didnt notice until I turned on touch simulation in the dev tools is that its completely busted on mobile with touch, however working fine with browser scroll in mobile view.

If anyone has any thoughts please let me know, you can find my site here: https://imaleks.dev/

Sorry in advance if this breaks any ettiquite new to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, when all you containers are `width: 100%` + `translateX(290px);`, and this is more then 100%. You should toggle some class to a `body` with `overflow-x: hidden;` when the mobile menu is active.

Or you can keep `overflow-x: hidden;` for `body` permanent. This will completely disable horizontal scroll.

Comment: So this got me on the right path - assigning overflow-x: hidden to body broke a lot of stuff but it kept the functionality of the menu to how I intended. Taking a deeper look I had to readjust my wrapper and remove some css from it and assign it to individual sections and that seems to have solved it! Thanks alot :)